# Allow users to add a webpage within a website

Tags: php, mysql, html, ftp

I'm trying to work out if there's a way that I could possibly implement a feature to my website that would allow a user/guest to create a new web page that will be stored on the server without needing to go through an FTP directly.
I'm looking for really basic functionality at the moment, just a basic form that will allow anybody to submit the name of a webpage that will then be stored in the root directory of the server. Anyone know if this is possible?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need a CMS - or alternatively, possibly a wiki? Alternatively, if you're thinking about Unix users on a server (eg. people with user accounts), you'd probably be looking to set up home pages in each user account. More detail about what you need would be very useful.

Comment: This could be done in many ways, I would not advise on storing it in files but within a database much like a CMS. tho giving free-write to any system, your just end up with users abusing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! Basically what I'm looking to create is a website that is based on user generated content. So yes a user based website where they would have the ability to add pages to the website in different categories and it would be published to the website subject to an admin/moderators approval. Users can then rate, review and follow certain pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For automatic html page generation through forms, you'll need to learn scripting languages such as php.

Comment: Hey @RossEdelman, nice to see that you're trying to answer questions. Might have been better if you'd phrase your answer beginning with something like "One way to do this is...".

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just unaware there were other ways. I'm only a student in web development, there is still a lot of things that I haven't learned.

Comment: No worries. Good to see you helping others.

Comment: how exactly would you go about doing this using PHP?!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wiki. Try [MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org) which lets your users create new pages. The follow feature is enabled by default as "watch a page" and the rate feature could also be used (as in WikiPedia) with some extensions (look for Article Feedback extension or similar ones).

Comment: Looks like a wiki based website is the way to go, thanks. There are a couple of more features that I want to implement but I'm not sure if it can be done through a wiki.
I need a news feed that I can place on the homepage that will show users updates on all the pages that they have followed/subscribed to. These updates are to be provided by users aswell. To give an example of what I mean. two links - one that allows users to add new pages (already available) and a second link that allows users to post news specific to a page. If a user is following that page it would then show up in the feed.

Comment: IMHO there will be an extension that lets you do that, besides the hundreds of extensions out there you can always build a new one or request one